# TypeOrm condition on queryBuilder and entityManager preforms differently

Tags: typeorm

I found these queries have different result but the logics should be same, did I do something wrong or it is a bug?

```
console.log(
  await em
    .createQueryBuilder(OrderItemEntity, 'orderItem')
    .where({ id: orderItem.id })
    .andWhere({ ownedByInvoice: IsNull() })
    .getCount(),
  ); //->0 correct, expected result

console.log(
   await em.count(OrderItemEntity, {
     where: { id: orderItem.id, ownedByInvoice: IsNull() },
   }),
 ); //->1 incorrect, count the one has ownedByInvoice
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling query level logging([Logging | TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/logging#logging-options)) in TypeORM and you can find out what is the query generated by TypeORM

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).